# Addition Loop in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, loops, assembly

I'm trying to make a loop that adds all the numbers between 1 and 20 ( 1+2+3+4+5....+20) and to my understanding it goes something like this but it says there was a build error when i try to run it. I thought ax is the number that you start with and then ecx was the number of times that the loop will perform then i increment a to make the number 1 higher each time. Can anyone see anything wrong?

```
.data
    a = 0

.code
main PROC
    mov ax, 0
    mov ecx, 20
    addLoop:
        inc a
        add ax,ax
        loop addLoop
    call DumpRegs
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Build errors happens, when your source code is not syntactically correct, and they usually have some exact string to help you identify what kind of error was detected, and in which source file at what line. That said I don't recall any x86 assembler supporting something like `a = 0`, probably `a dw 0` may fix the build error. It will still not produce the result you want any way, because there's different logic of the code then you describe in text. But once it will build, you can at least debug it in debugger.

Comment: Btw, you don't need separate variable/register for the numbers from 1 to 20, you already have them in your loop without `a`, but they are just going downward from 20. Doesn't matter, as long as you want to sum them, the result will be the same.